# How to cascade delete entities with unidirectional 'ManyToOne' relationship with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, openjpa

I have two entity classes 'User' and 'Department' with unidirectional 'ManyToOne' relationship as below.

```
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", nullable = true)
    private Department department;
}

public class Department{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

If I want to delete some users and cascade remove the referenced departments if not any user references the department, is there any features of JPA to use please?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CascadeType.DELETE`, however this annotation only applies to the objects in the `EntityManager`, not the database. You want to be sure that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is added to the database constraint. To verify, you can configure JPA to generate a ddl file. Take a look at the `ddl` file, you'll notice that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not part of the constraint. Add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to actual SQL in the `ddl` file, then update your database schema from the ddl. This will fix your problem .

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) shows how to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on for `CONSTRAINT` in MySQL. You do this on the constraint. You can also do it in a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement. It's likely that JPA creates the constraint in an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Simply add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to that statement.

Note that some JPA implementors do provide a means for this functionality.

Hibernate does supply this functionality using the `@OnDelete` annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind reply. But I am sorry that we are not allowed to implement this on the database layer, and only standard JPA could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: Have the same problem ATM.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell hibernate to delete 'orphan' entries with;

```
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
```